# Android - How to immediately endCall with telephonyService?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

In my application, there's a feature that ends outgoing call (and starts other activities) while dialing a certain number (e.g. `*123*`)

It's currently working, but requires a 200ms delay. Without the delay, the intent cannot be recieved.

The delay causes a consequence of multiple screen flickers:

`my activity shows` -> `switch to call` -> `end call` -> `switch back to my activity`

```java
public class OutgoingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // ...
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ...
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            // ...
            if(number.equals("*123*")) {
                // ...
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'v seen other applications with this special-number-dialing feature, the call ends immediately wihout the end-call-beep, and switches to app activity without flickering.

**Q1:** Does anyone know how to end call without delay? Is there another intent that we can catch before `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`?

**Q2:** On a mobile phone with low specs (slow CPU, less memory), would `BroadcastReceiver` work the same way as on a decent phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer...

To end an **outgoing** call **immediately**, we don't even need to call `endCall()` from `ITelephony`, instead, we can simply use **setResultData(null);**

It's different from manually ending a call or using endCall, with `setResultData(null)`:

- No notification icon or message
- No calling screen
- No call time toast
- No call log
- No end call beep

It's just like nothing happened (if...without any other extra activities).

```java
public class OutgoingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // ...
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ...
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            // ...
            if(number.equals("*123*")) {
                setResultData(null);
                // start other activities
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Does anyone know how to end call without delay?

> > here is the answer [Blocking/Ending incoming call](http://www.questoid.com/Articles/tabid/190/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/2/Blocking-Incoming-Call.aspx)

Is there another intent that we can catch before ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL?

> > **No**

Q2: On a mobile phone with low specs (slow CPU, less memory), would BroadcastReceiver work the same way as on a decent phone?

> > **Yes**